# adaptar bordes de un objeto al contenedor

Tags: html, css

Hola buenas tengo una duda, quiero que los bordes de este objeto (el azul), se adapten a los bordes del contenedor, ya que no quiero ir poniendole border radius en los laterales, quiero que automaticamente se adapten a los border del contenedor. Gracias.

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/949450759387369492/949463280555024475/218_20220305012748_1.png?width=1193&height=671);
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: #b65084;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#b65084 0%, #ca59d0 80%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,#b65084 0%, #ca59d0 80%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg,#b65084 0%, #ca59d0 80%);
    width: 70vw;
    height: 40vw;
    border-radius: 2.5vw;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8vw #b134b8;
}
#left-panel {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 12vw;
    height: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="App.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="left-panel"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Iba agregar una respuesta con `inherit` pero acabo de buscar y [no está soportado](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_csspropertyrule_inherits) por muchos navegadores. De cualquier forma una  posible solución podría ser agregar en el contenedor interno `border-top-left-radius: inherit;` y 
`border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;`, pero no es la más óptima. Creo que la mejor forma sigue siendo estableciendo ambos al mismo valor.

Comment: overflow-y:hidden al .container el detalle ahi es que si el contenido del interior sobrepasa la altura del contendor pues se va a quedar oculto.

Comment: Creo que te estás complicando, simplemente haz:  `.padre , .hijo { border-radius: 10px }` al agregar la coma ***`,`*** no tienes que estar cambiando valores entre cada elemento padre y su hijo. Revisa: https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/css/capitulo-2/selectores-basicos